# JSON and AJAX with Python

Tags: javascript, python, django, json

I am using Python/Django to submit some JSON to the client. Do I have to parse it, or can I just start calling things out of it like I would any other object?

Comment: you would use `json.dumps()` to send the object to the client, and access it a normal javascript json object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `json` module to convert from a json string to a Python dict:

```
import json
json_str = '{"foo": "bar"}'
d = json.loads(json_str) # d = {'foo': 'bar'}
```

Or from a Python object to a json string:

```
import json
d = [1, 2, 3, 4]
json_str = json.dumps(d) # json_str = "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
```